# ILM new index does not obey my policy limit GB

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a policy using the index pattern `logstash-*` and with alias `logstash-rollover`. My first index is `logstash-001` and it was created manually by me and attached to rollover alias.

After 50GB (my policy set max 50GB), another index is created: `logstash-002`, and it is ok for me. The problem is my second index get about 200GB and more, seems like policy is not applied to other indexes different from `-001`.

Index `-001` : (check policy)

[image]

Index `-002`: (no policy here)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

The `ILM policy name` does not work with a pattern it is just the name of the policy.

You need to create an index template, which hold the ILM policy. This index template does use an index pattern, which should match your indices.

[This tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html) explain it nicely.

## Solution

Create a template

```json
PUT _index_template/automated_ILM
{
  "index_patterns": ["logstash-*"],                   
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index.lifecycle.name": "<Your ILM policy name>"
      "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "logstash-rollover"   
    }
  }
}
```

Apply the ILM policy manually to the index `logstash-002`

```json
PUT logstash-002/_settings 
{
  "index": {
    "lifecycle": {
      "name": "<Your ILM policy name>"
    }
  }
}
```

The do the rollover manually

```json
POST logstash-rollover/_rollover
```

And you should be all set.

Comment: I tried it , using template, but after the second index is created I got error: "two write indexes to same alias",  because template attach the name alias for all indexes.

Comment: Creating the template should not create an error.

Comment: The issue must be during the rollover phase if I am correct?

Comment: Actually it happens in logstash side, because I'm using the alias to write data to the indexes, and if there is multiple write indexes it gives me error in logstash

Comment: Yep, then just remove it from one of the index. But I am not sure how you end up with 2 write index with this.

Comment: Ok, worked. My mistake here I was using the wrong alias.